# Asp.net FindControl + "Multiple controls with the same ID"

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I'm getting a really weird behavior with ASP.Net.
When I run the following code, the exception "Multiple controls with the same ID" is thrown.
The exception is not thrown when adding the control but when using `FindControl`.

What's really weird is that if I put a breakpoint just before the call and run a `FindControl` call in the immediate windows where the exception is thrown (so far so consistent) but then when I resume the debugger, everything works fine (!!!). The machine runs the same exact code but, it doesn't throw the exception again.

One last thing about this crazy thing, earlier today the very same code was inside Page_Load and everything was working fine but I reorganized the code and moved it to a separate method (which is called by Page_Load).
I'm getting pretty confident this is a ASP.Net bug...

```
    dlAdvanced.DataSource = dsAdvanced;
    dlAdvanced.DataBind();

    // Load Advanced Values Controls
    #region ADV controls
    foreach (DataListItem dli in dlAdvanced.Items)
    {
        DataRow row = dsAdvanced.Tables[0].Rows[dli.ItemIndex];

        switch ((string)row["Type"])
        {
            default:
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "Input";
                dli.FindControl("InputPlace").Controls.Add(tb);
                break;
            case "System.Int32":
            case "System.Decimal":
                TextBox tbn = new TextBox();
                tbn.ID = "Input";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.SkinID = "NumberRequired";
                img.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
                dli.FindControl("InputPlace").Controls.Add(tbn);
                dli.FindControl("InputPlace").Controls.Add(img); // Exception happens here
                break;
            case "System.DateTime":
                golf.golfControls.CalendarBox cal = new golf.golfControls.CalendarBox();
                cal.ID = "Input";
                cal.SkinID = "Calendar";
                cal.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
                dli.FindControl("InputPlace").Controls.Add(cal);
                break;
            case "System.Boolean":
                RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
                rb1.Text = "True";
                rb1.ID = "Input";
                rb1.GroupName = "grp" + dli.ItemIndex.ToString();
                RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
                rb2.Text = "False";
                rb2.ID = "Input2";
                rb2.GroupName = "grp" + dli.ItemIndex.ToString();
                dli.FindControl("InputPlace").Controls.Add(rb1);
                dli.FindControl("InputPlace").Controls.Add(rb2);
                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

**EDIT** :
I just though of something and it worked :

```
        DataRow row = dsAdvanced.Tables[0].Rows[dli.ItemIndex];

        var inputPlace = dli.FindControl("InputPlace");

        switch ((string)row["Type"])
        {
            default:
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "Input";
                inputPlace.Controls.Add(tb);
                break;
            case "System.Int32":
            case "System.Decimal":
                TextBox tbn = new TextBox();
                tbn.ID = "Input";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.SkinID = "NumberRequired";
                img.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
                inputPlace.Controls.Add(tbn);
                inputPlace.Controls.Add(img);
                break;
            case "System.DateTime":
                golf.golfControls.CalendarBox cal = new golf.golfControls.CalendarBox();
                cal.ID = "Input";
                cal.SkinID = "Calendar";
                cal.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
                inputPlace.Controls.Add(cal);
                break;
            case "System.Boolean":
                RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
                rb1.Text = "True";
                rb1.ID = "Input";
                rb1.GroupName = "grp" + dli.ItemIndex.ToString();
                RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
                rb2.Text = "False";
                rb2.ID = "Input2";
                rb2.GroupName = "grp" + dli.ItemIndex.ToString();
                inputPlace.Controls.Add(rb1);
                inputPlace.Controls.Add(rb2);
                break;
        }
```

So for the time being, my code works fine, but this issue isn't resolved so if someone knows anything about this bug, please enlighten me.

Comment: Also, it's impossible for us to reproduce your bug on our machines with the code you've posted now. Is there any chance you could write up a minimal example that reproduces the bug, but that we can run on our own computers?

Comment: @Thomas I don't think I can, as I said, simply having moved this bit of code to a separate method made the bug appear so if I'm not mistaking this ASP.Net behavior is completely random

Comment: Feel free to compare the code with the bug and the code withouth it and make a guess on why dli.FindControl("InputPlace") works the first time it's called in a iteration, doesn't work the second time and works again the third time (when I "cheat" my way doing the 2nd call from the immediate windows).

Comment: @Thomas, BTW, though you can place default were you see fit, C# don't allow breaking through cases (except for "code empty" cases).

Answer (score 0):

it is not a bug, all your controls has the same ID `tb.ID = "Input";` `cal.ID = "Input";`, etc

try to add a unique string after each ID like

```
tb.ID = "input" + dli.ItemIndex.ToString();
```

Comment: I've read that often already but it's not relevant here.
Those controls don't share the same naming container, thus their UniqueID aren't the same. Otherwise the new code wouldn't work (and it wouldn't ever have worked either).

Answer (score 0):

**The problem actually came for an event that tried to add those controls again elsewhere in the code**.

*I just answer my own question so it's a closed matter, no rage downvote for this responsible behavior please.*